# element is not getting updated after the setState gets changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs.

Here, I am trying to show a spinner on a button which is like

```
<button type="submit"
    style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 10 }}
    className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
    onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>
        {<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> && this.state.isloading}
        Login
</button>
```

Now, Here ,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userName: '',
        passWord: '',
        isloading: false
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.clickedLogin) {
        this.setState({
            isloading: true
        });
    }
}
```

So, when user clicks on the button then I am dispatching one action and then with this I am getting a prop using mapStateTOProps.

But right now, when I click on the button, it is not showing that spinner.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: The prop `clickedLogin` passed from the parent component is probably not changing thats why the `componentWillReceiveProps` hook doesnt run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
{<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> && this.state.isloading}
```

to

```
{this.state.isloading && <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>}
```

Comment: Yes man Thanks a lot :-)  I don't know How I have not observed that

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit. I know this is very easy, but still

Comment: @GaneshKaspate read [MDN: Logical Operators > Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) and [JavaScript — Short Circuit Conditionals](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb)